# Wrap the heap allocate memory for a generic type in Arc?

Tags: templates, rust

I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a generic type and want to wrap the generic type in an Arc. However, I am getting a segmentation fault.

The code is working fine when I wrap the `T` in `Box`, which means that semantically there is no issue with the code.

Moreover, the code is working fine when I use `Vec::with_capacity()`, instead of dynamically allocating the memory using `alloc()`.

```
struct Entry<T>
where
    T: Sized + Clone + Default,
{
    val: T,
}

struct Entries<'a, T>
where
    T: Sized + Clone + Default,
{
    vec: &'a [Cell<Entry<T>>],
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> Entries<'a, T>
where
    T: Sized + Clone + Default,
{
    fn new<'b>() -> Entries<'b, T> {
        let bytes = 64;
        let mem = unsafe {
            alloc(Layout::from_size_align(bytes, align_of::<Cell<Entry<T>>>()).expect("Error"))
        };

        let num = bytes / size_of::<Cell<Entry<T>>>();
        let raw = unsafe { from_raw_parts_mut(mem as *mut Cell<Entry<T>>, num) };

        Entries { vec: raw, index: 0 }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, val: &T) {
        self.vec[self.index].set(Entry { val: val.clone() }); // Error here
        self.index += 1;
        println!("Appended");
    }

    fn remove(&mut self) {
        self.index -= 1;
        println!("Removed");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut log = Entries::<Arc<u8>>::new();
    let element = Arc::new(8);
    log.append(&element);
    println!("Reference Count for Arc {}", Arc::strong_count(&element));
    log.remove();
    println!("Reference Count for Arc {}", Arc::strong_count(&element));
}
```

**Questions**

1. Why is `Box` working and `Arc` not working for dynamically allocated memory?
2. Why is `Arc` working when the allocation is done using `Vec::with_capacity()` but not when `alloc()` is used?

**Playground Links**

1. [Arc using `alloc`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=25d02d1c3351c0f6861e3c6195c92bd6) (Please change Arc to Box for the first case).
2. [Arc using `Vec::with_capacity`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=958bdb8798beeac883cd8d47b5db6913)

Comment: `core::ptr::write()` : Overwrites a memory location with the given value without reading or dropping the old value. So, `for e in &mut raw { core::ptr::write(e, Cell::new(Entry{val: val.clone() }))}` can be used to intialize the memory just after getting the `raw` slice for `n` elements.

However, be careful about all the issues which @trentcl has given in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is unsound:

```
let raw = unsafe { from_raw_parts_mut(mem as *mut Cell<Entry<T>>, num) };
```

It is not correct to create a reference to a slice of `num` elements because 0 elements have been initialized. When `T` is `Arc<u8>`, which is a pointer type, this means they may point to arbitrary data, or be null. If you only created the slice reference and never dereferenced it, it might work, but this line:

```
self.vec[self.index].set(Entry { val: val.clone() });
```

will try to drop the `Arc` already in the `Cell` before replacing it with the new `Arc`. Dropping the `Arc` frees the pointer, which because it is uninitialized causes undefined behavior.

> Why is `Box` working and `Arc` not working for dynamically allocated memory?

By accident, basically. `Drop` for `Box` just passes the pointer to `free`, but `Drop` for `Arc` has to follow it in order to check the reference counts. If the memory comes initially zeroed, with a typical allocator, `Box` may appear to work while `Arc` segfaults. However, you cannot rely on this behavior, which brings me to my next point:

> The code is working fine when I wrap the `T` in `Box`, which means that semantically there is no issue with the code.

This is not true. Because code *appears* to work correctly does not mean it is free of bugs! Even the `Box` version is incorrect. The best way to avoid memory safety bugs is to not use `unsafe`. When you do use `unsafe`, you have to be careful to uphold all the invariants that safe code relies on, such as (in this case) "references must always be valid".

> Why is `Arc` working when the allocation is done using `Vec::with_capacity()` but not when `alloc()` is used?

`Vec::with_capacity` creates an *empty* `Vec`. When you call `Vec::push` on this empty `Vec`, it does *not* call `drop` on the uninitialized element at index 0; it just initializes it (and increases the length to 1).

This is a great example of why correctly using `unsafe` is trickier than it may appear, and why most Rust programmers prefer to use thoroughly tested and reviewed data structures such as `Vec`, rather than rolling their own using `unsafe`.

(`Entries` has at least one other problem, which is that the data it references may never correctly be deallocated; because `new` creates an `Entries` with an arbitrary lifetime, you could use it to get a reference to the inner block that outlasts the `Entries` object itself. The data created by `alloc` cannot be deallocated and is therefore unowned. Fixing this problem boils down to using a bit more `unsafe`, and recreating most of `Vec` inside `Entries` — but why bother, since `Vec` already exists?)